# How to model a Multiple Choice Question Database?

Tags: database-design

I am going to create an multiple choice based examination system. I am new to database design and want your help to answer a few questions.
How to model the questions and answers?

- Each question will have four options and only one correct answer.
  option 1:

```
create a table for questions, options and answer:
question:
  question_text varchar

options:
  question_id int primary_key,
  options_text varchar

question_answer: for storing the correct answer
  question_id int foreign_key,
  answer_id int foreign_key

user_question_answer:  # for storing the response of user.
  user_id int foreign_key,
  question_id int foreign_key,
  answer_id int foreign_key
```

option 2:
store question, options and correct_answer in a single table.

```
question:
  question_text char,
    option_1 varchar,
    option_2 varchar,
    option_3 varchar,
    option_4 varchar,
    answer enum(1,2,3,4)

user_response:
  user_id int foreign_key,
  question_id int foreign_key,
  answer enum(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is a fail - what if people suddenly have 3 or 5 options? REWORK THE WHOLE SOFTAWARE? Also, not relational - the word relation has a meaning there. multiple tables.

Comment: There will always be four option.

Comment: Famous last words. Really. That is how the year 2000 problem came around.